# Independent vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

A sequence of vector fields on an open subset of a manifold is linearly independent in module sense, i.e., if we multiply by smooth functions. Does it imply the pointwise independence of the vector fields?

Comment: I'd say not in general. First they should be parallelizable in your manifold, $M$, and then your manifold should admint `$n=dim(M)$` parallelizable vectors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No: consider the vector fields $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the condition that the submodule generated by those elements is a direct summand then this is true. Proof: the other summand must be projective, so locally free, so at each point the sequence forms part of a basis, so is linearly independent.